# Content Rating Option disabled in Store Listing on Google Play Developer Console

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, rating, google-play-developer-api

I am an android developer and have been developing apps over 2 years but for the first time i have encountered an issue of such sort that i'm going to describe below.
I hope i will get a problem solving answer upto my satisfaction.

**Issue:**

⦁   I'am unable to select "everyone" option in content rating while preparing store listing for my upcoming  app say app2.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2X6f.png)

⦁   I searched out on Internet for my issue and here on stackoverflow too but all i get was that this problem is caused by permissions that we use in android manifest.

⦁   The thing i need to mention is that i have already published an app say app1 with similar permissions that i'm using in app2 .

⦁    The content rating "everyone" option was not disabled while preparing store listing of  app1. But it's disabled here while doing same thing for app2.They say " Some rating options have been disabled based on the content of your application. ".

⦁   Kindly help me out of this issue and if any one knows other reasons that might have caused this issue then please tell me her. Below are the permissions that i'am using.

[**Permissions**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bmmx.png)